# How to pass %{THE_REQUEST} to a php file with htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get a download system using PHP working and having one small issue.

I have this in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.*$ process.php?%{THE_REQUEST}
```

I am urls like this:

```
/download/path1/path2/some file name.pdf
```

In my php the $_GET looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [GET_/download/path1/path2/some_file_name_pdf?q] => somevalue HTTP/1.1
)
```

This works fine, I can replace the underscores with a space and all works well.  The problem is that when the file name actually has an underscore in it will break since I am replacing underscores with a space since the majority of files have spaces in the names. Only a few files actually have an underscore in the name and this is something I cannot change.

This is the problem:

```
/download/path1/path2/some_file_name.pdf
```

In my php the $_GET looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [GET_/download/path1/path2/some_file_name_pdf?q] => somevalue HTTP/1.1
)
```

So is there a way with htaccess to replace a space in %{THE_REQUEST} to some character like (~) or character sequence like (__) or something like that?

Comment: Why not just pass the request to process.php instead of doing a query string and then in PHP use `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`

Comment: How do I pass the request to process.php with htaccess?

Comment: Attach it as actual parameter `?thereq=%{THE_REQUEST}`, not just as literal query string.

Comment: `THE_REQUEST` is the "full HTTP request line sent by the browser", it's not simply the URL. `THE_REQUEST` also contains the request method (eg `GET`, `POST`, etc.) as well as the protocol version eg. `http/1.1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already passing it, but just don't use $_GET. Try this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule . /process.php [L,NE]
```

Then in PHP

```
print_r($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```

Then you can explode on `/`.